# .join function won't work in loop

Tags: python, syntax

does the function below properly use the .join function? I was attempting to make a board of all O's without the quote marks and commas. The output is the same as the input for board and doesn't remove the commas or quotation marks. I'm new to Python so I haven't yet grasped the proper methods for using these built in functions.

```
board = []
for x in range(5):
    board.append(['O'] * 5)

def print_board(oChart):
    for row in oChart:

        #this line below is were the error occurs
        " ".join(row)

        print row


print_board(board)
```

When run the output is :

```
['O','O','O','O','O']
['O','O','O','O','O']
['O','O','O','O','O']
['O','O','O','O','O']
['O','O','O','O','O']
```

the output I intended to receive:

```
[O O O O O]
[O O O O O]
[O O O O O]
[O O O O O]
[O O O O O]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`join` *returns* the string.  It doesn't change `row`.  Do `print " ".join(row)`.

Note that this won't include the brackets.  If you want them, you'll need to print them yourself.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you aren't doing anything to save the value of `" ".join(row)`.  You are concatenating the strings and then throwing away the result.

Try `print " ".join(row)`.